# Specify how many hops back to go / prevent redirect returnining to current site

Tags: firefox, browser

I used to use this trick quit a bit but can't seem to find it any more. How do you go back to a specified page by using the back button? Or go back more than one page? This is an issue because if an intermediate redirect page is in place, if you click the back button you just end up back on the current page. I remember in older versions of internet explorer, there was a little drop down arrow beside the back button on the toolbar, and you can specify which particular site you want to go back to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long-click on Firefox's `Back` button or `Forward` button . It will show you a list of the sites you have visited, and you can click on any one of them to navigate directly to it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks never would have guessed this myself. I don't know why they made this useful feature so hidden.